# Learning curve for Asp.net MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am Asp.net developer having a bit experience in web application development.Want to learn ASP.NET MVC 5.

Want to Know :

Can I directly start MVC 5 or else need to dig into earlier ASP.net MVC?

Are there any specific things i should know before learning MVC?

How to go through leaning the framework?

What all design patterns are essential to be known?

Please help me I am completely in a dilemma.

Comment: Why not just start with some tutorials and see how it goes?  I see no reason not to at least *try* to learn.  What exactly is the "dilemma" here?

Comment: @David Thanx for responding.Yes I started but facing difficulties in learning as there is use of Lambda expression,extension methods etc which i was not knowing so needed to learn them first so asked this doubt and want to known what all i am missing.

Comment: Well, those are just C# concepts which have nothing to do with MVC.  If you don't know C# particularly well then, yes, ASP.NET MVC isn't going to be entirely familiar.  But you should be able to pick up the concepts side-by-side while learning the framework.

Comment: ok. so you mean I should do what I am doing. go for MVC and if there is some C# concept I am missing go for that concept.Thanx Again !!

Answer (score 2):

You can directly dig into ASP.NET MVC 5. This book will be of a great help: 
[Professional ASP.NET MVC 5](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-5.productCd-1118794753.html)